# BotBuilder: Authenticate users using Microsoft Open Graph?

Tags: node.js, authentication, botframework, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to create a web chat bot and would like users to authenticate using Microsoft Open Graph. I can't find any documentation on authentication except for Azure AD which is not what I'm looking for. How can I allow users to sign in using Microsoft Open Graph in the web chat bot?

Comment: Graph doesn't sign folks in. Graph requires an Azure AD-issued token, so the Azure AD stuff is probably what you're looking for. I'm guessing what you're wanting to do is to be able to make Graph API calls on the user's behalf?

Comment: Nevermind... it's all documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-tutorial-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-3.0#to-register-an-azure-ad-v2-application). I guess I wanted users to sign in using Azure AD.

Answer (score 0):

It's all documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-tutorial-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-3.0#to-register-an-azure-ad-v2-application).

I had to use [Microsoft's Application Registration page](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/?referrer=https%3a%2f%2fportal.azure.com%2f#/application/71713776-9c2c-470d-9b99-eb41a4c97286) and the link explains each step.